# Postback URL Code For Locker

Tags: php, url, postback

Let me explain the story, so  I am starting a website users can join and track stuff from a website, I want to create a postback link that inserts 'payout' into the table with the locker code, but when I try and test it, it gives me this error

```
Execute failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
```

So here is the code that I used...

```
<?php

define("MYSQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("MYSQL_PORT", "3306");
define("MYSQL_DB", "dbuser");
define("MYSQL_TABLE", "userpayout");
define("MYSQL_USER", "user");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "dbpassweord");

$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .
$mysqli->connect_error;
}
$aff_sub1    =         $_GET['aff_sub'];
$aff_sub2   =         $_GET['aff_sub'];
$aff_sub3   =         $_GET['aff_sub'];
$aff_sub4   =         $_GET['aff_sub'];
$aff_sub5   =         $_GET['aff_sub'];
$aff_sub6   =         $_GET['aff_sub'];
$payout     =         $_GET['payout'];


if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".MYSQL_DB.".".MYSQL_TABLE." SET 
payout=payout+(?) WHERE aff_sub1=(?)"))) 
{
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
 }
$stmt->bind_param('ds', $aff_sub1, $aff_sub2, $aff_sub3, $aff_sub4, $aff_sub5, $aff_sub5, $payout);
if (!$stmt->execute()) 
{
  echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
else
{
  printf("%d Row updated, added $".$payout." to locker ".$aff_sub1." .\n",

mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
}

?>
```

So I am trying to track multiple aff_subs which are the lockers that they get the payout from. I want to insert it into the row with the same affsubs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the variables `$aff_sub1`, `$aff_sub2`, `payout` etc. before calling `bind_param` to make sure they are set.

Also make sure the postback link is invoked via GET method, since you are retrieving the variables from `$_GET`.